# Shiny App clickable points not working with log scale y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

For the first time I really can't find this answer here already, so I hope you all can help me, I'm sure there is a pretty easy fix.

I am making a Shiny volcano plot with clickable points to give me a table with the data about that point. If I use a trans function (that I found here, thank you helpful stranger) within scale_y_continuous() in my plot, points in the scaled region are no longer clickable. How can I scale the axis this way and still be able to have the clickable points?

My code, with some fake data that has the same problem:

```
## Read in necessary libraries, function, and data 
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)

reverselog_trans <- function(base = exp(1)) {
    trans <- function(x) -log(x, base)
    inv <- function(x) base^(-x)
    trans_new(paste0("reverselog-", format(base)), trans, inv, 
              log_breaks(base = base), 
              domain = c(1e-100, Inf))
}

pretend_data <- tibble(data=1:5, estimate = runif(5, min = -1, max = 2), plot = c(1e-50, 2e-35, 5e-1, 1, 50))

# Define UI for application that draws a volcano plot
ui <- fluidPage(
    # Application title
    titlePanel("Pretend Plot"),
        plotOutput("plot", click = "plot_click"),
        tableOutput("data")
 )

# Define server logic required to draw a volcano plot
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(data = pretend_data, aes(x=estimate, y=plot)) + 
            geom_vline(xintercept=c(-1, 1), linetype=3) +
            geom_hline(yintercept=0.01, linetype=3) +
            geom_point() + 
            scale_y_continuous(trans = reverselog_trans(10))
    }, res = 96)
    
    output$data <- renderTable({
        req(input$plot_click)
        nearPoints(pretend_data, input$plot_click)
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `input$plot_click` returns the coordinates on the *transformed* scale. `nearPoints` tries then to match those to the *original* scale which does not work.

You have a couple of options though:

1. Transform the data yourself and adapt y axis ticks via `scale_y_continuous`
2. Adapt `pretend_data` in the `nearPoints` call.

#### Option 1

This requires that you control y axis tick marks yourself and would need some more fiddling to get the exact same reuslts as in your example.

```r
pretend_data_traf <- pretend_data %>%
   mutate(plot = reverselog_trans(10)$transform(plot))

# Define UI for application that draws a volcano plot
ui <- fluidPage(
   # Application title
   titlePanel("Pretend Plot"),
   plotOutput("plot", click = "plot_click"),
   tableOutput("data")
)

# Define server logic required to draw a volcano plot
server <- function(input, output, session) {
   output$plot <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(data = pretend_data_traf, aes(x=estimate, y=plot)) + 
         geom_vline(xintercept=c(-1, 1), linetype=3) +
         geom_hline(yintercept=0.01, linetype=3) +
         geom_point() +
         ## would need to define breaks = to get same tick mark positions
         scale_y_continuous(labels = reverselog_trans(10)$inverse)
   }, res = 96)   
   output$data <- renderTable({
      req(input$plot_click)
      nearPoints(pretend_data_traf, input$plot_click)
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

#### Option 2

```r
pretend_data_traf <- pretend_data %>%
   mutate(plot = reverselog_trans(10)$transform(plot))

# Define UI for application that draws a volcano plot
ui <- fluidPage(
   # Application title
   titlePanel("Pretend Plot"),
   plotOutput("plot", click = "plot_click"),
   tableOutput("data")
)

# Define server logic required to draw a volcano plot
server <- function(input, output, session) {
   output$plot <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(data = pretend_data, aes(x=estimate, y=plot)) + 
         geom_vline(xintercept=c(-1, 1), linetype=3) +
         geom_hline(yintercept=0.01, linetype=3) +
         geom_point() +
         scale_y_continuous(trans = reverselog_trans(10))
   }, res = 96)   
   output$data <- renderTable({
      req(input$plot_click)
      nearPoints(pretend_data_traf, input$plot_click) %>%
         mutate(plot = reverselog_trans(10)$inverse(plot))
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of what was causing the problem- I thought something like that would be the issue, but I am not adept enough to know how to fix it. Option 1 works perfectly for me, and putting in the breakpoints manually is actually a plus.